# Regex - How to create an expression to present a result that is enclosed in commas?

Tags: regex

---

Order Id 008577:

Pickup Time: 2021-07-08 16:30:00

Pick-up: FACILITY-1, 106 NORTH RAM CENTER BLVD, SEATTLE, WA, 92338

Deliver: FACILITY-2, 2304 NORTH 22ND AVENUE, SUITE B, Pasco, WA, 99001

MEMO: Station: 1A | Notes: Oliver,James Ready: 4:00pm

---

I need to write the information of Line "Pick-up" and "Deliver" separately to the database.
How should I use the Expression to select just the , CITY, or just ,STATE, or feathers , ADDRESS,

I plan to create an expression for each Information I need to write to my database in separate columns.

How it is:

|Pick-up: FACILITY-1, 106 NORTH RAM CENTER BLVD, SEATTLE, WA, 92338|

How I wish:

|FACILITY-1|

|106 NORTH RAM CENTER BLVD|

|SEATTLE|

|WA|

|92338|

I appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: How are you reading this information? is it text based? which language are you using? Python?

Comment: Split each line based on delimiter ":". Match first element to be "Pick Up" or "Delivery". Then Split string based on delimiter ",". It will provide you the required tokens.

Comment: @Luiz Cesar - What outcome do you wish for the _Deliver_ line?

Comment: Hi Armali,  
As an example, in the "Deliver" line extract only the address.   [ 2304 NORTH 22ND AVENUE, SUITE B ]

Comment: Hi Pooja Sonkar,  I am using "Parser" software.
This is extracting the information from an email to write to the Mysql database.
This email is standard formatted, all the lines I was able to save as I wanted in the database, except "Pick-up" and "Deliver" , because my database needs the information from these lines separately, writing in separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Luiz, I just tested this for your given string

```
/([A-Za-z0-9-/\s]+)/g
```

I used regextester.com to verify it.

Comment: If you wish to ignore Pick-up then ([^,up|Pick:-])([A-Za-z0-9-/\s]+)

Comment: Hi Ismail,   Thank you so much for helping me with this.

I tested: ([^,up|Pick:-])([A-Za-z0-9-/\s]+)    

This separated and presented all the information divided one on each line.

For example, How do I make the Expression extract only the information ,CITY, in the "Pick-up" line?

Comment: @LuizCesar are you using JavaScript for this?

Comment: @LuizCesar regardless of the language, results are usually available in an Array which you can access with an index. For example results[0], results[1] and so on

Comment: I'm using an "EmailParser" platform it seems to handle this with JavaScript.